# AngularJS: Duplicate directive on click without sharing the same data between elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to build a Search Engine selection directive where there are 2 dropdowns (1 for search engine and 1 for country)
However, I have managed to get it working, but I would like to be able to add another Search Engine after the first one has been selected, but also, limit them to a maximum of 3 search engines.

This is were I am stuck as duplicating the directive will obviously make the selection the same across all 3 search engines.

In `HTML` the directive looks like this:

```
<wiz-engine-selector>
    <wiz-engine selected-engine="knc.selectedEngine"></wiz-engine>
    <wiz-country selected-country="knc.selectedCountry"></wiz-country>
</wiz-engine-selector>
```

Any ideas how I can duplicate the directive without them sharing the same data?

Here is a demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KbmDBkM1sDJJM6OAYPAI?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I solved your issue using a ng-repeat on your directive.

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0YyxOp9MCDv5p3dD7Oo?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
    <wiz-engine-selector ng-repeat="engineSelector in engineSelectors">
        <wiz-engine selected-engine="engineSelector.selectedEngine"></wiz-engine>
        <wiz-country selected-country="engineSelector.selectedCountry"></wiz-country>
    </wiz-engine-selector>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  //Each engineSelector will have its own set of variables into the engineSelectors array.
  $scope.engineSelectors = [{
    selectedEngine : { icon:{}, name:{} },
    selectedCountry : { flag:{}, name:{} } 
  }];
  $scope.addAnother = function(){
     $scope.engineSelectors.push({
        selectedEngine : { icon:{}, name:{} },
        selectedCountry : { flag:{}, name:{} } 
     });
  };
})
```

If you want to limit to three search engines just add a limit in the "addAnother" function